# change and ngModelChange do not fire on select control in Visual Studio 2017 of an Angular 4 app running in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, angular, google-chrome, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have an Angular 4 application that is hosted in an ASP.NET application that I am trying to debug on my Windows 10 64 bit laptop in Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.3).

If I set a breakpoint on the ngModelChange (or change) event of a select control, once this event is triggered (I choose a new item in the dropdown), then the application freezes and never reaches the breakpoint in Visual Studio 2017. If I then hit F12 (which starts Chrome's Developer tools), the application unfreezes but by doing this, Visual Studio is no longer the debugger and the breakpoints in Visual Studio don't get hit.  Other events, such as ngOnInit fire and work fine and even the ngModelChange event works on other controls.

I found the following errors in the Output window:

- This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored.  The thread 0x2f74 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
- Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

I want to be able to debug my typescript code in Visual Studio using Chrome as the browser.

Please help.

Comment: Debugging in the browser tools does not suit your needs ? You can use `debugger;` instruction in your Typescript code.

Comment: The recent Visual Studio versions are not very stable, especially with the debugger...

Comment: Hi Pac0, Thanks for looking at my issue.  My problem isn't that I have no way to debug, as you say I could use chrome, my problem is I want to debug in Visual Studio 2017 where all my other code (C#) is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio 2017 bug in version 15.3.3.  When I try the same code on a pc with Visual Studio 2017 (15.2) it works.

I have reported the issue to Microsoft. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/106262/change-and-ngmodelchange-do-not-fire-on-select-con.html